# PowerShell script that modifies Word file doesn't work with Task Scheduler when user isn't logged on

Tags: powershell, batch-file, ms-word

I have a PowerShell script (launched through a batch file) that is run through Task Scheduler.  When the task is configured to "run only when user is logged on" then it runs fine.  When the task is configured to "run whether user is logged on or not" it still runs but PowerShell spits out errors.

The script takes a Word file, makes some formatting changes then exports it as a PDF file.

Here's the relevant batch code:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /R E:\Originals %%x in (*.doc) do (
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& E:\Scripts\FormatReports.ps1 %%x"
)
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
```

Here's the relevant PowerShell code:

```
#start Word
$word = New-Object -comobject Word.Application
#open file
$FilePath = $args[0]
$document = $word.Documents.Open($FilePath)
$word.Visible = $false
#modify orientation and margins
$document.PageSetup.Orientation = 1 #Set to Landscape
$document.PageSetup.TopMargin = $word.InchesToPoints(0.25)
$document.PageSetup.BottomMargin = $word.InchesToPoints(0.25)
$document.PageSetup.LeftMargin = $word.InchesToPoints(0.25)
$document.PageSetup.RightMargin = $word.InchesToPoints(0.25)
#save as a pdf file
$NewFilename = $FilePath.replace(".DOC","")
$document.saveas([ref] "$NewFilename.pdf", [ref] 17)
#close and exit Word
$document.close([ref]$false)
$word.Quit()
```

Here's the errors:

The property 'Orientation' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At E:\Scripts\FormatReports.ps1:43 char:1

- $document.PageSetup.Orientation = 1 #Set to Landscape
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
  ```

The property 'TopMargin' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At E:\Scripts\FormatReports.ps1:44 char:1

- $document.PageSetup.TopMargin = $word.InchesToPoints(0.25)
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
  ```

The property 'BottomMargin' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At E:\Scripts\FormatReports.ps1:45 char:1

- $document.PageSetup.BottomMargin = $word.InchesToPoints(0.25)
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
  ```

The property 'LeftMargin' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At E:\Scripts\FormatReports.ps1:46 char:1

- $document.PageSetup.LeftMargin = $word.InchesToPoints(0.25)
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
  ```

The property 'RightMargin' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At E:\Scripts\FormatReports.ps1:47 char:1

- $document.PageSetup.RightMargin = $word.InchesToPoints(0.25)
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
  ```

I have only a basic knowledge of PowerShell scripts, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have not provided a [mcve] of your batch file code. We need to know the contents of that variables and if that paths are network drives.

Comment: I cannot provide a reference but it is well known that MSFT Office does not work properly without an interactive user session. It is not supported by MSFT.

Comment: I have updated the code example to show that all files are local.

Comment: I may have found the answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24916290/powershell-script-run-from-task-scheduler-unable-to-open-word-document

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674836/how-to-run-a-windows-2008-task-from-the-scheduler-with-interact-with-desktop

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be the missing folder in the system profile, as described here:

[Powershell script run from task scheduler unable to open word document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24916290/powershell-script-run-from-task-scheduler-unable-to-open-word-document)

[How to run a Windows 2008 task from the scheduler with "interact with desktop"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674836/how-to-run-a-windows-2008-task-from-the-scheduler-with-interact-with-desktop)